# How to solve this North and South Sitting arrangement puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

10 friends A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J are sitting in a row. Some of them are facing north while others are facing south. Not more than 2 persons facing the same direction sit together. They all have their birthdays in different months of the same year. Persons born in consecutive months are not sitting adjacent to each other. C sits 4th to right of A, who sits at one of the extreme ends. Only 4 persons face to the south. No one has a birthday in April or in May. C has a birthday in a month which has 30 days. The person having a birthday in February sits to the immediate right of the person having a birthday in October, and both face the same direction. D, who has a birthday in September, sits fourth to the left of B, whose direction is opposite that of A. F has a birthday in August. Neither B nor D is an immediate neighbour of C. E, who has a birthday in March, sits to the immediate right of J, who is 3rd to left of the person who has a birthday in January. I neither faces south nor has a birthday in October.

Now the questions:

1. Who has a birthday in December?
2. Who sits 2nd to right of the person who has a birthday in June?

The question has been taken from a source called Practice Mock. Will full permission of reproduction.

Comment: Is "to the right of X" considered from X's point of view or from an outside observer's?

Comment: X's point of view @msh210

Comment: Are they sitting in a row oriented east-west?

Comment: So we know that A must be at the far left end, and C fourth to the right. I can't figure out other things just yet, but I'll work on it.

Comment: To clarify: here's a helpful table. ~ means NOT.
We need to know 3 things: orientation, month, and position
A: 1, *, *

B: *, *, ~A

C: 4, *, *

D: *, Feb, *

E: *, Mar, *

I: *, ~Oct, Nor

Comment: Nothing is said about G and H, except for the 1st sentence.  So either the solution is not unique, or the actual identity of G and H does not affect the 2 questions at the end.

Comment: @someoneinexistence Please give me qa more structural answer.

Comment: It's helpful for others.

Comment: If "Practice Mock" refers to practicemock.com, then that's an inaccessible website.

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem Not that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a fun puzzle. Thanks for posting it.

I think it needs more conditions because I found 2 different answers and strongly suspect that there are many more.

> [image]

Who has a birthday in December?

> I and A

Who sits 2nd to right of the person who has a birthday in June?

> D and B

Edit: Here was my thought process:

I started with a diagram representing all possibilities, and then deleted the things that were not possible, step by step. And I had to go back through the steps over and over. Finally, when I was out of clues to apply, I started making guesses and comparing the final results to the rules and to each other. I never finished that final step because I immediately found duplicates. (You may have to zoom in a bit on your browser to really see the details in the pics below.)

[image]

Note: Sometime during the process of solving this, I realized that the North-South issue could be solved at the end when I set all of the direction arrows that had not been set, so there is no need to keep 2 separate diagrams (1 for each direction), since one will always be 180° of the other.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

At this point, I didn't see anything else that I could cross out, and eventually decided to try different scenarios based on the following two rules that were not yet fully applied/resolved:

1. E, who has a birthday in March, sits to the immediate right of J,
   who is 3rd to left of the person who has a birthday in January.
   (since there are just 2 possibilities), and
2. The person having a birthday in February sits to the immediate right of
   the person having a birthday in October, and both face the
   same direction. (3 possibilities)

Here are the 6 possibilities I found:

[image]

[image]

At this point I took the results and removed the rest according to the rules. I did that with one of the other resulting diagrams and they both matched the rules, so I stopped my analysis and posted what I had.

Since I quickly found multiple different layouts that answered the questions differently, I highly suspect that there are many more different layouts that would fit all the rules. A fun puzzle, nevertheless.

Comment: Hey, welcome back JLee! Looks like your first post here since the glory days of 2015 :-)

Comment: Yeah, I missed you guys. I'm back!

Comment: Since the title asked "how to solve" perhaps you could walk through it a bit?

Comment: I also got lost in too many possibilities.